# Sequence density in the interval

Tags: real-analysis

Is this true that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \ne 0$ and for all $\psi \in [0,2\pi)$ there exists a sequence $n_m$ satisfying $(n_m)^{i\cdot a} \to e^{i\cdot \psi}$ and $(n_m)^{i\cdot b} \to 1$?

Comment: Let $a=b$ and $\psi\neq0$

Comment: If $b/a$ is rational, then we can get only finitely many values $\psi$.  But if $b/a$ is irrational ... ?

Comment: Do you want $n_m$ to be a positive integer? Or any positive real number (in this case, the answer is positive when $a/b$ is rational).

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan: are you sure you have things the right way round? See Gerald Edgar's comment.

Comment: @Mark Wildon I made a typo. If each $n_m$ is any real number, the answer is positive if $a/b$ is irrational.